# standalone pipelined function calling another standalone pipelined function

Tags: oracle, plsql, pipelined-function

I want to write two pipelined functions, standalone, meaning outside of PL/SQL package:

```
create or replace function fn_test_1 
return sys.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL pipelined -- ODCIVARCHAR2LIST 
AS
BEGIN
  FOR l_row in ( ... )
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW('text');
    PIPE ROW('other text');
    PIPE ROW(strings_concatenated);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

create or replace function fn_test_2 
return sys.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL pipelined -- ODCIVARCHAR2LIST 
AS
BEGIN
  FOR l_row in ( select column_value as line from TABLE( fn_test_1 ) )
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW(l_row);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

`fn_test_1` compiles successfully and works fine. However I cannot compile `fn_test_2` becuase of:

```
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

Can I even write standalone pipelined functions one calling the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're return a cursor and not the value it has, use this:

```
create or replace function fn_test_2 
return sys.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL pipelined -- ODCIVARCHAR2LIST 
AS
BEGIN
  FOR l_row in ( select column_value as line from TABLE( fn_test_1 ) )
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW(l_row.line);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: I just spotted this and wanted to post this, but you were first :) thank you